# MVC solution structure

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I feel kinda silly to ask this but I've been looking for a little while and found no complete answer yet, let's say I've a MVC website, for the structure i've followed this post:

[Architectural decisions: ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515623/architectural-decisions-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework)

```
WebSite (MVC)
   Controllers
   Views
   Content (scripts, css, images, etc.)

Presentation Models
   View Models
   Model mappers

Web Library
   Extensions (to MVC/Web classes)
   Helper Classes
   Attributes

Business Logic
   Rules  

Data (if complex, use separate subfolder per context/repos/models)
   Entity Models
   Repositories 
   Data Context

General Library
   Extensions
   Helper Classes
```

1) where should i put my link queries for searching data?

I thought about creating a general search in my BL with search object that could be reused if needed for another application (let's say mobile app or winform app) and then return general search object that will be  mapped thru the Presentation model project? 
I am not sure queries are 'business logic/rule'.

Or should i do all this queries directly in the Presentation Models project?
If so, I would assume I still need to create general object first so i could reuse the same query for some other device or so.

2) Let's say I want to add a mobile application on top of this, should i put every viewmodel in the same Presentation Models project for both Web and mobile?

3)Should every call from the web flow thru the Presentation layer even for input validation and CRUD operation?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herewith I have given my opinion on the points that you have made query here
1) where should i put my link queries for searching data?

***If your Linq queries are associated with some search conditions or so, use them in the BL layer. ***
2) Let's say I want to add a mobile application on top of this, should i put every viewmodel in the same Presentation Models project for both Web and mobile?

*** you will be required to do so ***

3)Should every call from the web flow thru the Presentation layer even for input validation and CRUD operation?
*** Always any validation should be done in both the places: presentation tier and in the BL so that when you later expose your services for WCF, it will be functioning without any exception. Even if presentation tier validation is skipped, it is fine. But BL validations are always fail safe***